# Novice Mathematica User: Plots are very small despite changing image size option

Tags: plotting, modeling

I'm currently writing a paper about marine chemistry and I'm trying to include a reactive transport model that was written in mathematica by a collaborator. I have a lot of experience in SAS, but I know next to nothing about mathematica. One issue I'm encountering is that the graphs produced by this model come out super tiny, and I'm not able to increase the size by changing the Imagesize option. I'm not sure if there's a local setting I have that's different than the person who wrote this model, but the image size is normal until I run the program, and then it becomes unreadable after I run it.

Below is a snippet of the code and the graphs that are generated. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Reactive Transport Graphs]

Comment: what happens if you do the same thing but without the `Print` command in the front?

Comment: Please post your actual code rather than just a screenshot.  Doing so will enable others to better help you.

Comment: Try the `ImageSize` option to `GraphicsGrid`. (From the docs: "If the Subscript[g, ij] are graphics with ImageSize->Automatic, GraphicsGrid will if possible resize them to make them fit into the grid as well as possible, while preserving their individual aspect ratios.")

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SetOptions[Plot, ImageSize -> 200];

gr1 = GraphicsGrid[
  Table[Plot[a*Sin[x + p], {x, 0, 6 Pi},
    PlotLabel -> StringForm["a = ``; p = ``",
      a, NumberForm[N[p], {5, 2}]]],
   {a, 1, 3}, {p, 0, Pi/2, Pi/8}]]
```

[image]

```
AbsoluteOptions[gr1, ImageSize]

(* {ImageSize -> {600., 219.016}} *)
```

Use the [`ImageSize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) option in [`GraphicsGrid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html)

```
gr2 = GraphicsGrid[
  Table[Plot[a*Sin[x + p], {x, 0, 6 Pi},
    PlotLabel -> StringForm["a = ``; p = ``",
      a, NumberForm[N[p], {5, 2}]]],
   {a, 1, 3}, {p, 0, Pi/2, Pi/8}],
  ImageSize -> 1200]
```

[image]

```
AbsoluteOptions[gr2, ImageSize]

(* {ImageSize -> {1200., 438.032}} *)
```

Use [`Grid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) instead of `GraphicsGrid`

```
Grid[
 Table[Plot[a*Sin[x + p], {x, 0, 6 Pi},
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["a = ``; p = ``",
     a, NumberForm[N[p], {5, 2}]]],
  {a, 1, 3}, {p, 0, Pi/2, Pi/8}]]
```

[image]